# Scrapy+splash при парсинге русского текста выдает юникод

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

При парсинге русского текста scrapy возвращает юникод.

вот результат сохранения в json:

`[ {"name": "3-\\u043a\\u043e\\u043c\\u043d. \\u043a\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u0438\\u0440\\u0430, 150 \\u043c\\u00b2"} ]`

Также результат сохранения в csv:

`,name 0,"3-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d. \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 150 \u043c\u00b2"`

(я пытался использовать .decode и .encode, но получается тоже самое)

также в настроках scrapy я написал `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` , но это не помогает.

При парсинге английского текста все хорошо,такое происходит только с русским.

вот сам код

```
class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    url = 'link'
    name = 'link'
    allowed_domains = ['link']
    start_urls = ['link']
    script = '''
           function main(splash, args)
             splash.private_mode_enabled = false
             assert(splash:go(args.url))
             assert(splash:wait(3))
             splash:set_viewport_full()
             return {splash:png(), splash:html()}
           end
       '''


    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script})

    def parse(self, response):

        name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [name]})
        df.to_csv("result.csv")
        yield {
            "name":name,
        }
```

Comment: можете показать код, которым вы используете для экспорта в json?

Comment: scrapy crawl link -o result.json

Comment: судя по документации, вы должны были добавить конфигурацию для Scrapy в settings.py, это делали? FEED = 'json'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

Comment: да,но это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
print(u"3-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d. \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430, 150 \u043c\u00b2")
```

Кодировка iso-8859
или это поможет
[Как перекодировать текст сайта в кодировке чтобы он был читаемым?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328837/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-cp1251-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC)